# label and input in same line on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to get label and input field in the same line when the width is big enough, and on separate lines when the width is too small.

This actually works, see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qCmxZ/).

HTML Code:

```
<div style="border-bottom-width:0;" data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="ti_gebdat">Geburtsdatum</label>
    <input name="ti_gebdat" id="ti_gebdat" style="text-align: right" type="date"  data-theme="d">
</div>
<div style="border-bottom-width:0;" data-role="fieldcontain">   
    <label for="oeffDienst">Öffentlicher Dienst</label>
    <select name ="oeffDienst" id="oeffDienst" data-role="slider">
        <option value="0">Nein</option>
        <option value="1">Ja</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

But, as you can see at the jsFiddle, the controls jump to the next line way too early. How can I have it stay on the same line until the controls really would overlap?

I am using jQuery-Mobile and testing on android, where the controls are always on separate lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your fiddle updated with a different solution that does not use media queries: **http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/qCmxZ/3/**

In this solution, instead of using the "fieldcontain" role provided by jQM, I am just putting the label and control in separate divs set to display inline instead of block.  Then between each line I clear the floats.

```
    <div class="dispInlineLabel" >
        <label for="ti_gebdat">Geburtsdatum</label>
    </div>
    <div class="dispInline">
        <input name="ti_gebdat" id="ti_gebdat" style="text-align: right" type="date"  data-theme="d" />
    </div>
    <!-- Clear floats for each new line -->
    <div class="clearFloats"></div>

    <div class="dispInlineLabel" >  
        <label for="oeffDienst">Öffentlicher Dienst</label>
    </div>
    <div class="dispInline">
        <select name ="oeffDienst" id="oeffDienst" data-role="slider">
            <option value="0">Nein</option>
            <option value="1">Ja</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

In the CSS, set the min-width so that all your labels and controls are appropriately sized, then as you resize the page, the controls will only wrap when the page is no longer wide enough to display the combined min width.  Here is the CSS:

```
.dispInline, .dispInlineLabel{
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom-width:0;
}
.dispInlineLabel{
    min-width: 150px;
}
.dispInline{
    min-width: 200px;
}
.clearFloats{
    clear:both;
}
```

You have to somehow "tell" the system when the controls would overlap, and I am doing that with the min-width css.

Answer (score 1):

As Human mentioned, the media queries are responsive for the change of the element order. In your jQuery mobile CSS `450px` is the magic width at which the elements will no longer be aligned side by side.

You *could* overwrite the stylesheet with a custom rule, so that the style for widths above 450px is applied no matter the screen size. You could do this by simply overwriting the selectors in question (http://jsfiddle.net/qCmxZ/1/):

```
@media all {        
    .ui-field-contain input.ui-input-text,
    .ui-field-contain textarea.ui-input-text,
    .ui-field-contain .ui-input-search {
        width: 78%;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .ui-field-contain label.ui-slider,
    .ui-field-contain label.ui-input-text {
        vertical-align: top;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20%;
        margin: 0 2% 0 0;
    }
}
```

However – unless done consistently – this is is not a smart idea since you alter the core of how jQuery mobile's input fields react to small display sizes.

So better consider reading up on responsive Web Design.

Comment: I need to have that exact site in the jsFiddle. With 2 conditions:1.If the label and the control can be displayed in one line they should. 2. if they cannot, they should show in 2 lines.

Comment: How can responsive web design help with this task? How is it, that everyone says that "responsive web design" is the solution, but nobody can show how?

Comment: In your case repsonsive web design is not the "solution"; it is the problem. jQuery mobile is (among other things) a responsive web design framework.

You are applying responsive web design logic (media queries) to your web site by using jQuery mobile. The media queries are the reason for the web site not to behave in the way you do expect it to.

Comment: P.S.: As I said, I am not going to be able to provide you with a "fix" since what you are experiencing is the expected behaviour of the framework you are using.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Now I'm starting to understand the problem. But, I have to use jQM, and I need this behavior. Is there no way to achieve this? Can't that specific problem be overwritten?

Comment: Of course, it is only about CSS rules. You can easily overwrite them. This is what I did in the jsfiddle. Be warned though that this might lead to inconsistencies. You could get inspiration for proper CSS at http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/forms/ The "Sliders" are similar in layout to what you are aiming to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem with you. Inspired by mritz_p's answer, I managed to work around this "issue" by adding a customized css file in the page. The css code is copied from the jqm css file, with a little adjustment to the min-width label width and .ui-controlgroup-controls.

For reference, here's the css code:

```
@media (min-width: 28em) {
    .ui-field-contain,
    .ui-mobile fieldset.ui-field-contain {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 1em 0;
        border-bottom-width: 0;
    }
    .ui-field-contain:before,
    .ui-field-contain:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
    }
    .ui-field-contain:after {
        clear: both;
    }
    .ui-field-contain > label,
    .ui-field-contain .ui-controlgroup-label,
    .ui-field-contain > .ui-rangeslider > label {
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
        margin: .5em 2% 0 0;
    }
    .ui-popup .ui-field-contain > label,
    .ui-popup .ui-field-contain .ui-controlgroup-label,
    .ui-popup .ui-field-contain > .ui-rangeslider > label {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        margin: 0 0 .4em;
    }
    .ui-field-contain > label ~ [class*="ui-"],
    .ui-field-contain .ui-controlgroup-controls {
        float: left;
        width: 78%;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    /* ui-hide-label deprecated in 1.4. TODO: Remove in 1.5 */
    .ui-hide-label > label ~ [class*="ui-"],
    .ui-hide-label .ui-controlgroup-controls,
    .ui-popup .ui-field-contain > label ~ [class*="ui-"],
    .ui-popup .ui-field-contain .ui-controlgroup-controls {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .ui-field-contain > label ~ .ui-btn-inline {
        width: auto;
        margin-right: .625em;
    }
    .ui-field-contain > label ~ .ui-btn-inline.ui-btn-icon-notext {
        width: 1.75em;
    }
}
```